# How to prompt for file save location using grim?

Tags: scripting, screenshot, sway

I currently use Sway/grim to save screenshots, but it is not obvious to me how to improve this by prompting for a filename. In other words, right now a typical binding in my sway config is as follows:

```
bindsym Print exec grim -g "$(slurp)" "$HOME/screenshots/$(date '+%y%m%d_%H-%M-%S').png
```

This allows me to select a region of the screen, screenshot it and then save it using a date-like filename to my $HOME/screenshots directory. Another related command I use is the following:

```
exec grim -g "$(slurp)" - | wl-copy
```

So, this puts the image on the clipboard, but often I want to save the image to a particular directory.

However, sometimes I would like to do the same thing, but have the option to pick the directory. So, I would want it to take the screenshot, activate a directory choose dialog and then save the file to that directory. Ideally maybe there is a way to activate the Wayland built in file chooser somehow. I tried using yad ("yad --file-selection") but when I run it, it just comes with a blank screen. Maybe because I am running Arch/Wayland/Sway?

One answer below has a terminal-based way to do it that is a little awkward. I really would rather just have a file save dialog box come up.

Comment: yad does not complain about invalid options for some reason. try `yad --file` instead (and ignore examples that still say --file-selection in the manpage...). alternatively try `zenity --file-selection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. It uses `fd` and `fzf` and specifies the destination *before* taking the screengrab.

```
#!/bin/bash

folder=$(cd && fd -a -t d | fzf)

sleep 10

grim -g "$(slurp)" "$folder"/"$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)".png
```

Save that as an executable and then modify your `bindsym` to:

`bindsym Print exec foot -e /path/to/executable`

Assumptions:

- You're using `foot`; change the bindsym to have the terminal you use and specify the actual path to the executable.
- the terminal should have an assigned workspace and the screengrab is **not** of that workspace

When you press <kbd>Print</kbd>, a terminal window will open in the workspace dedicated to that terminal.
It will display a directory tree powered by `fzf`.
Choose the directory in which you wish to save the screengrab by scrolling and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
You'll have 10s to move to the relevant workspace.
When the 10s elapses, the pointer changes to cross-hairs. Select the area.
The image will be saved in the directory you chose.